# How to split a string to a list in this job? Java

Tags: java, regex

**I have a String like this.**

```
<body>
Search Results:
<br>
<br>

    Member ID: 10149
    <br>
    Title:
    <br>
    First Name: Skye
    <br>
    Middle Name: Susan
    <br>
    Last Name: Sommers
    <br>
    Comment: Entry Report completed.
    <br>
    Time Stamp: 2011-10-13 14:43:36
    <br>
    Select Agent: Century 21
    <br>
    Agent Details: Peter Thorpe Century 21 33 Diamond Drive Newcastle NSW 2300
    <br>
    Street: 49 Fairway Court
    <br>
    Suburb: Newcastle
    <br>
    Postcode: 2300
    <br>
    <br>
    Member ID: 10149
    <br>
    Title:
    <br>
    First Name: Skye
    <br>
    Middle Name:
    <br>
    Last Name: Sommers
    <br>
    Comment: Qtr inpection showed residence in very good condition. Walls and floors very clean. Back and front yard both neatly kept.
    <br>
    Time Stamp: 2011-10-13 12:40:31
    <br>
    Select Agent: Century 21
    <br>
    Agent Details: Peter Thorpe Century 21 33 Diamond Drive Newcastle NSW 2300
    <br>
    Street: 49 Fairway Court
    <br>
    Suburb: Newcastle
    <br>
    Postcode: 2300
```

How to split String its into a Array with array with first member is:

```
Member ID: 10149 
 Title: 
 First Name: Skye 
 Middle Name: Susan 
 Last Name: Sommers 
 Comment: Entry Report completed. 
 Time Stamp: 2011-10-13 14:43:36 
 Select Agent: Century 21 
 Agent Details: Peter Thorpe Century 21 33 Diamond Drive Newcastle NSW 2300 
 Street: 49 Fairway Court 
 Suburb: Newcastle 
 Postcode: 2300
```

Thank for helping!

Comment: Could you reformat your question a bit please: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help It is not clear what you're trying to do (is it HTML you get as input, or did you post HTML to format the question here on SO?). Also, could you also post what you have tried yourself and explain how that failed? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What ideas do you have? First you should think about the procedure to follow. By example start reading lines, for each one identify which field it is, add it to some temporal structure and go on. Decide when you must generate a new member (by example, when you find member_id field). Then if you have trouble for doing something (splitting lines, remove whitespace, iterating, whatever) post a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to do quickly because of the potential conflicts.  You can use `String.replace()` to drop the `<br>` tags.  Then you could do a `String.split()` on the word "Member", but then it would break if "Member" shows up anywhere else.

A more controlled, but complex method, would be to `split()` on newlines and then read each line, checking for a `startsWith()` and then filling in the appropriate data.  Considering your result above isn't much more helpful, this would also allow you to actually create a `Record` object and fill it in, line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Your order of elements is not changing, however you want to create a `List` of of beans.
May I suggest using [Apache Commons DynaBeans](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html) instead in this situation? They are objects that you can create on the fly and access values by using `bean.get("key");` and you can set values by using `bean.set("key", "value");`

So what you can do is split your html using something like follows:

```
String html = "<your html>";
List l = new ListArray();
int index = 0;
while((index = html.indexOf("Member", index)) > -1) {
   //nextIndex is the end of the first element.
   int nextIndex = html.indexOf("<br>\n<br>",index);
   String element = html.substring(index, nextIndex);
   //parse element string to create dynabeans
   DynaBean bean = createDynaBean(element);
   l.add(bean);
   index = nextIndex;

}
```

I havne't provide the code for creating a dynabean. take a look here for an example on how to [create a dynabean](http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/beans-sect-dyna). Since you have a string prepresenting 1 element in your `List` it should be easy to use `split()` or `indexOf()` etc to get the values for the elements you want. I would start by splitting on `\n` and then split on `:` which would give me key and value for each line.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this pseudo-code:

```
Member newMember = null;
List<Member> result = new ArrayList<Member>();

for each line
   trim whitespace
   // control new objects
   if line starts with "Member ID:"
      if newMember != null
          result.add(newMember);
      newMember = new Member()

   // add values to the current object
   else if newMember != null (at the beginning there's no created object)
      if line starts with "field1:"
         newMember.setField1(parse value from line)
      else if line starts with "field2:"
         newMember.setField2(parse value from line)
```

It should suffice if your input is well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution for chopping it up:

```
String[] parts = input.split("(?m)\\s*(^.*<.*$)+\\s*");
```

From the input above, this will give you:

```
[, Search Results:, , Member ID: 10149, Title:, First Name: Skye]
```

Iterate over it, ignoring the stuff you don't want. Assuming "Search Results:" marks a new person, do this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> peopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> person = null;
for (String part : parts) {
    if (!part.contains(":") || person == null) continue;
    if (parts.startsWith("Search Results")) {
        person = new HashMap<String, String>();
        peopleList.add(person);
        continue;
    }
    String[] nameValue = part.trim().split(":");
    person.put(nameValue[0].trim(), nameValue[1].trim());
}
```

Now you have a list of maps, each with entries like "Member ID"="10149" etc

Comment: but I wanna [{Search Results:, , Member ID: 10149, Title:, First Name: Skye},{Search Results:, , Member ID: 10149, Title:, First Name: Skye} ...]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
// remove spaces and tags
html = html.replaceAll("(?m)(<.*?>|Search Results:|^ *)", "");
// remove empty lines
html = html.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
// split by newlines
String[] results = html.split("\\n")
// use results
```

You can then split each `results[i]` with `:` to get key and value.

Answer (score 0):

First split according to`<br>\n<br>`  and then split the arrays[1] element with `<br>` character, then iterate over all splited strings and thake whatever you want.